# Detecting sexually explicit content

Tags: images, parental-control, computer-vision

I am looking for a program that

- Can detect the presence of sexually explicit images
- Works either on Windows, Linux or Android

If possible:

- Accurate
- Free
- Can scan other documents (e.g. videos)

Comment: Real-time, or one-time scan?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Well I am actually looking for both :) Real-time to put on the kids' devices and send me an alarm or complain in some logs; one-time scan for devices where real-time is not practical (typically when I couldn't install the real-time scanner or I suspect the kids manage to disable it).

Comment: What should it do upon detection? Delete it, move it, or just display a pop-up *"File matsukodeluxe.jpg has 55% chance of being porn, you might want to have a look at it"* maybe?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul If one-scan, anything but deleting is fine (at least it should give me a way to view it to check). If real-time, put in quarantine (or any other way so that the kids can't see it easily).

Comment: What's your definition of sexually explicit? Any nudity at all? Even if it's guy in a bathing suit? How much tolerance do you have for false positives?

Comment: @MichaelKohne Pretty much anything that would be considered inappropriate for children less than 10-12 year-old. It's pretty vague indeed. I much prefer a (reasonably) low precision over a low recall.

Answer (score 2):

I am using a program that works well in Windows only. It is called "Media Detective" and is available  [here](http://www.mediadetective.com/)

It is only a scanner of files and internet history and does not have real time protection. It scans pictures and videos and attempts to detect the "Skin Color". If too high a percentage of skin color is present it flags the picture/video and assembles it for later review.

At the end you have the option to select & delete all the pictures.

Additionally it checks text files of explicit content and other keywords you can set. It also checks internet history and usage.

It has a 14 day trial so you can check if it works for you.

This does not quite match your requirements but I hope this helps you or another person.

Answer (score 2):

Most sexually explicit images usually come from/are hosted off of sexually explicit websites. E.g. Porn Websites which are crawled and appear in search engines such as Google Images. Because of this I would recommend using a web filter such as K9webprotection.

It's free, can be used for personal use and is available on Android, IOS, Windows and Mac OS.

**You will need a license (free to obtain) to use it which can be obtained [here](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/get-k9-web-protection-free) after which you can download it for free.**

---

Once you've done that all you need to do is run the program you downloaded. (everything after this is pretty self explanatory), just accept the K9™ USE LICENSE AND SERVICES AGREEMENTS, enter in your license and setup a password for the web interface and then reboot your system.

---

### Now that you've rebooted your computer

Navigate to the web interface in your web browser address bar by typing the following

[image]

Next the K9 Web Protection Administration page will pop up. Click on setup and enter the password you set up during installation.

[image]

Then just tick Pornography & Adult/Mature Content.

[image]

And done. Technically sexually explicit images are blocked and have already been detected and placed into their appropriate categories.

Also just as a precaution you should probably tick **Open Image / Media Search** since some sexually explicit images sometimes get through. (unless you want to find out). ;)

---

Also for the video solution you might want to try K9's Advanced YouTube Filtering. (but this is just for YouTube and it's currently only experimental).

PS: It's pretty accurate having tried and tested it. Also my school uses Bluecoat for their webfiltering. :p

[image]

Hope it helps. :)